# Batch Script to get % CPU and % MEM Usage of particular process by PID

Tags: command-line, memory, batch-file, cpu-usage

Can you help me writing Batch script to get the Percentage CPU and Percentage MEM usage of a particular process by PID. I searched a lot but didn't found any solution.

1) Tried with `Tasklist` command but not getting Percentage MEM Usage of process.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /nh /FI "PID eq 9312"') do ( set total=%%a ) echo Memory = %total%
```

Output: Memory = 3,784

It is only showing Mem usage by process but need to get % Mem usage of process.

2) For % CPU Usage of particular process, tried `wmic` & `typeperf` commands but not getting required output.

It would be very helpful if someone could help with the commands or give some hint to get the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the %cpu and %mem using the `ps` command. You can get the full list of parameters you can ask `ps` by running `ps L`
For your particular case, I'd run:

```
ps -eo pid,%cpu,%mem | grep <pid>
```

Then you can use `cut` to extract each field.
Hope that works!

Comment: Wrong OS I expect!

Comment: I had the feeling that the script looked unreasonably odd. OP should probably remove the [bash] and [bash-scripting] tag and put the [powershell] one or whatever they're using!